# Is there any HQL tool like LinqPad

Tags: nhibernate, hql

I am new to NHibernate. For LINQ there is LinqPad to convert SQL to LINQ.
Does any one know if there is any HQL tool like LinqPad. I am using fluent nhibernate.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [HQL Language Service for Visual Studio](http://hqladdin.codeplex.com/) - it is probably the closest thing to an "HQL LinqPad" out there.